# Having the duplicate(calling twice) requests on every API calls with AngularJS with JWT Auth token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jwt, angular2-jwt

Having issue with AngularJS(2/4) when making API call. Each API Requests has JWT Auth Token header which make API duplicate where the first one return no response (but 200 statusCode) but the second request return the actual data.

Answer (score 2):

Discovered that it is a the behaviour of cross origin http request.

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) - when performing certain types of cross-domain Ajax requests, modern browsers that support CORS will insert an extra "preflight" request to determine whether they have permission to perform the action.